# How to print untrusted html blob in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, xss

I am loading a blob from an API with content type text/html, this blob is completely based on user-input and therefore not trusted, it may contain e.g malicious script that grabs the access_token from local_storage and sends it to some web server.
What's the best practice for safely printing such a blob?

My code currently loads the blob in a hidden sandboxed iFrame and calls print(). However a perfect sandbox will prevent calling print() on the iFrame content, so I had to add **'allow-same-origin'** and **'allow-modals'** exceptions to the sandbox. But I am not sure if or how those exceptions compromise security:

```
/**
 * Attaches the given blob in a hidden iFrame and calls print() on
 * that iFrame, and then takes care of cleanup duty afterwards.
 * This function was inspired from MDN: https://mzl.la/2YfOs1v
 */
export function printBlob(blob: Blob): void {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.onload = setPrintFactory(url);
  iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
  iframe.style.right = '0';
  iframe.style.bottom = '0';
  iframe.style.width = '0';
  iframe.style.height = '0';
  iframe.style.border = '0';
  iframe.sandbox.add('allow-same-origin');
  iframe.sandbox.add('allow-modals');
  iframe.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

function setPrintFactory(url: string): () => void {
  // As soon as the iframe is loaded and ready
  return function() {
    this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
    this.contentWindow.__url__ = url;
    this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
    this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
    this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
    this.contentWindow.print();
  };
}

function closePrint() {
  // Cleanup durty once the user closes the print dialog
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.__url__);
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Is there a particular use-case you have for supporting HTML? For example, *could* you use a different approach? Perhaps support Markdown (with included support for HTML), or even BB-codes (legacy but you get the idea), *if* you can avoid directly dealing with code you probably should, otherwise strip all <script> tags, strip all <element> tags that aren't required by your application. Santiser functions may help you here.

Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html looks very promising to solve this problem, allowing you to determine exactly what tags should be present.

Comment: I want to implement printing functionality (e.g. printing invoices) based on a user defined HTML template. Any other markup language would do as long as all browsers know how to print it. The problem with sanitizer tools is that they strip away <style> tags, which undermines the whole point of having HTML templates.

Comment: Typically HTML should be converted to PDF on the server side and the PDF served to the client, but I have not found a cheap library that can do that in my server environment (ASP.NET Core), so I'm serving the HTML blob as is and relying on the user agent to do the printing which works well, but introduces this security problem.
The solution should be some trick for opening and printing the untrusted HTML blob in a place that's isolated from the rest of the app, such that any script in there becomes harmless.

Comment: Generally, it's never a good idea to allow for raw code input, *however*, in your case it does make sense, my suggestion from above is still relevant, although I think Markdown and BB-code would be unneeded for your use-case, certainly won't help for layouts + printing (without modification).

I'd remove **all** tags you do not need, as a bare minimum, **always** remove <script> tags, there's no functional reason to have them.

For testing in isolation, could something like Selerium work here? Although it's mainly used for testing, it's actually browser automation.

Comment: Although not ideal, it *may* be an option to manually review uploaded HTML files, convert the file to plain-text and have an admin review it (in plain-text), convert it back to HTML if safe, or render as HTML (either or). *I mean you could get real fancy and do something with machine learning to accomplish a similar goal.*

I'm just throwing suggestions here, there's really no right answer, I'd use a layered approach to reduce the risk of serious harm, strip tags, semi-auto verification, plain-text conversion, sanitize the HTML also.

Comment: As a final thought, it's always worth considering the effect that XSS would have on your application, how many users it would effect, what would happen to business, etc.. 

The answers to these kind of questions are how you'll determine how much up-front effort you're willing to invest, you could end up rabbit holing into a number of technical solutions against a minimal threat. Or you could end up with the opposite: leaving yourself vulnerable.